# Azure SQL backup restore from Microsoft?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Our Azure SQL database had two columns removed.  Unfortunately we did not have a backups or restore points enabled.  Does Microsoft take a daily backup of our data? if so how do we get it back?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, even if you are using the cheapest tier, you are offered 7 days of backups (more days on "better" tiers). You can find those in the portal.
And they are not daily, they are point in time.

Check this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-business-continuity or this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-sql-database-point-in-time-restore/